# How to install php debug symbols on Debian Buster?

Tags: php, coredump, debug-symbols, debian-buster

I am trying to obatin a meaningful backtrace for some segmentation faults occuring on php-fpm in Debian Buster.
Reading [Debian's guide](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace), I understand that

1. I need to add the debug repo `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug/ buster-debug main`
2. I need to install `debian-goodies` so that I can search my debug symbols package with `find-dbgsym-packages`

But it seems that the php debug symbols are missing from the output of `find-dbgsym-packages /usr/bin/php`, these are the packages listed:

- `libargon2-1-dbgsym`
- `libgcc1-dbg`
- `libicu63-dbgsym`
- `liblzma5-dbgsym`
- `libpcre2-dbg`
- `libsodium23-dbgsym`
- `libssl1.1-dbgsym`
- `libstdc++6-8-dbg`
- `libxml2-dbg`
- `php7.3-cli-dbgsym`
- `zlib1g-dbg`

I was excpecting to find a package like `php7.3-dbgsym`... what I am missing?

Comment: Any luck on this? Facing the same issue with 7.4. Tried to add --enable-debug to PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS in Docker file at https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.4/buster/apache/Dockerfile but gdb still says Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/php...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Answer (score 1):

> I was excpecting to find a package like php7.3-dbgsym... what I am missing?

You are missing that the debug symbols you need are included in `php7.3-cli-dbgsym`.

Install all of the packages `find-dbgsym-packages` finds and analyze your `core` again.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but the `gdb` `bt` looks the same (many `??` calls) as if no debug symbol was installed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can add an automatic downloader now:

> https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace#Automatically_loading_debugging_symbol_from_the_Internet

Just type this in your console:

```
export DEBUGINFOD_URLS="https://debuginfod.debian.net"
```

Then run your PHP script:

```
$ gdb -args /usr/bin/php my_faulty_script.php
(gdb) run
...
(wait for the crash)
...
(gdb) bt
```